# How do I edit/change tags?

Tags: support, tagging

I am trying got change the edit tag name from puertovallarta to puerto-vallarta. But I get this error message -

> You are attempting to create the tag puerto-vallarta ; however the tag
>   puertovallarta already exists!

How do I edit/change tags since that tag is linked to just one question as of now

Comment: You can always flag a question containing the tag to a moderator, choose "other" as a flag reason, and explain your what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I added this one without the hyphen.

I was trying to add it properly but for some reason every time I added the hyphen the system would remove it again. Then it wouldn't let me add the version with the hyphen once the wrong one was there because they were too similar.

So I flagged it for moderator attention, explained the problem, and somebody fixed it for me (-:

Answer (score 1):

I've added the [puerto-vallarta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/puerto-vallarta) and synonyms for it.
The only way this can be done by you is edit tags to the question.